# Karma with Angular Project return empty code coverage report when relocate tests

Tags: angular, testing, code-coverage

Because I don't need to test the used Angular base template and only need to test the base components and services, I relocated to the `src/tests` folder with the same inner structure of the `app` folder. Then I changed my `test.ts` file in order to reference the new path.

```
const context = require.context('./tests', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

If I run the next command:

`ng test`

I can get all tests passing, but if I run the next command:

`ng test --code-coverage=true`

It generates the report and I can see that, but with empty results.

How can I do to reference the new tests path?